# Two worlds diverged in a person's mind

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, video-games

A strange fellow in a cloak approached me and asked if I liked games. When I said yes, he gave me this note and said the two related final answers would be important to me.

> Now I ap proach, and ask you speak my name.
>   One woRld do I reside in, while *t*wo I furnish.
>
> As the newEst of old you pick up, you finD true conflict,
>   no amount of your actions can s ave brother s from the flame.
>   Still, you may t*r*y, or *y*ou may help explode the time bomb.
>   WHa tever you choose, the ending is one of which only I have an ide a.
>   Exp*lo*re anyway, and givE your *o*wn version your own pizzazz!
>   Really, I *k* now you'll be back when next I up date, for the adventuRe won't be m*in*i.
>
> So we tuRn the the other, the e arliest of the new **s**ell!
>   Here we can see, the end of known li fe.
>   Except, it's not o**v**er, yo u'll fi**n**d to your *g*rief,
>   realizing **t**hing**s** are dIfferen t. W**i**ll you understand? No.
>   E**x**pect to be stumped, at least when first my world you enter.
>   Maybe as time goes, you will see the path, but at first, yo u will lose
>   you r seNse of the worl d, time, and what was wrong with the pitch
>   for you and your love, wh ich got you so utterly lost.
>   Rather than Gi ve *up*, though, you get moving and re-learn the area.
>
> In du e time, in eitHer world, you wil*l* find your relief.
>   Even if you find the wo rld's end, you can always reset.
>
> Next, we *a*pproach the end of our *st*ory for
>   drawin g this out further will simply not do.
>   So, my fri en ds, can you speAk u*p*, or wil*l* you hush?
>   I think you know me. I'm sure you're *a*t no lo*s*s.

What's hidden in this puzzle that may mean something to me as a gamer?

Answer (score 4):

Well, in addition to some of the info posted already:

> The acrostic reads 'no answers here sy friends I'

and

> the italics, as noted read: try looking up, which suggests an acrostic from top to bottom, giving 'short fathel of Elizabethe' - which given the video game tag, could be Booker DeWitt of Bioshock

and

> the bold letters give svntsix, suggestive of 76, which is John Francis Morrison from Overwatch.

Together, this could be

> Francis Booker, an English cricketeer, which is hinted at by the word 'pitch', maybe.

The thing that escapes me is

> the spaces. reading letters on the right side of the spaces gives astndafuurdiverged. which is close to something (the 'diverged' is clear). EDIT: Now with the edits, this reads "Past and future diverged" which at least is readable, but I'm still missing something. Could have to do with the settings of the games (past and future).

So it's close, but not quite there yet.

Comment: For your first clue, I messed up my formatting, which means it will also alter clue two (though you actually still got that, minus a typo, nice catch!) You're on the right track, but you're right, you're definitely missing something. The text of the puzzle is not pointless. While the clues are hidden it it, more information is also sitting in plain sight. :)

Comment: Also, your "all together" answer is a great guess, but not sure how it might be important to me as a gamer. ;)

Comment: The rot13(fiagfvk) could refer to rot13(snyybhg)

Comment: @Mohirl You're walking down the right road with that guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously several messages encoded here...

1. > CAPITAL letters (ones inside verses, not at the beginning of lines) spell "RED HERRING HA" - fair enough...
2. > *italic* letters spell "try looking up last plas" - nothing I found looked even remotely game-related...
3. > **bold** letters spell "svntsix" - could be referring to HC SVNT DRACONES tabletop roleplaying franchise, maybe a specific book?
4. > no idea what to do with oddly placed spaces...

Comment: While you did find a couple of the clues (clearly you didn't figure out the last one, but that one was a little more... Confusing, as was my intention) You really only understood one of them, and there are two clues you didn't find. (One you did points to one you didn't.) Also, check the tags: the puzzle is related to video games. That may help you a bit.

Comment: Also, on the third clue, I didn't even know that franchise was a thing when I made that clue... Whoops! Noted for later use...